# Update all using alias from an aggregate value derived from a Join

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT activities.id, max(symbols.bought_at) AS bought_at 
FROM "activities" 
  JOIN holdings ON trackable_id = holdings.id AND trackable_type = 'Holding'   
  JOIN symbols on symbols.holding_id = holdings.id 
GROUP BY activities.id"
```

I have a SQL that looks like the above.  This works fine.  However, I want to update all activities' created_at to the alias bought_at.  I get an error that bought_at is not a column. Is it possible to do so in Postgres?

Comment: Do you actually want to change the data in the table, i.e. run an `UPDATE` statement to change the `activities` table?

Comment: I think you’ll have to use a row number analytic to do your maxing so that rows remain intact - I’d be amazed if pg can “remember” which row(s) a max aggregated value came from in order that an update of their value can be performed - you should appreciate that in a group by all the row data is mixed up with values coming from different rows, primary keys are effectively discarded (they can’t be retained because if they we’re every group in the result would have one row in it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I do want to run update all to change activities created at to bought_at

Comment: @CaiusJard wouldn’t join automatically map to the correct row

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question -> I thought you were wanting to update bought_at with the created_at value, (`SET bought_at = created_at` not `SET created_at = bought_at`) => the comment was describing the difficulty a database would have in remembering which row contributed to the max)bought_at) so that its bought_at value could be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use that query as the source for an UPDATE statement:

```
update activities 
   set created_at = t.bought_at
from (
  SELECT activities.id, max(symbols.bought_at) AS bought_at 
  FROM activities
    JOIN holdings ON trackable_id = holdings.id AND trackable_type = 'Holding'   
    JOIN symbols on symbols.holding_id = holdings.id 
  GROUP BY activities.id
) t
where activities.id = t.id;
```

This assumes that `activities.id` is the primary key of that table.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out in the morning and will update.